# Почему js не отображается?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JSexample</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="" method="post" name="test" id="form">
  <label for="name">Имя:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" id="name" /> <br/><br/>

  <label for="password">Пароль:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" id="password" /> <br/><br/>

  <label for="RePassword">Проверка пароля</label>
  <input type="password" name="RePassword" placeholder="Введите пароль" id="RePassword"/> <br/><br/>

  <span>Укажите пол (ваш)</span>
  <input type="radio" name="state" id="state1" value="Мужской"/>
  <label for="state1">Женский</label>
  <input type="radio" name="state" id="state2" value="Женский"/>
  <label for="state2">Мужской</label>
  <br/><br/>

  <input type = "submit" onclick="valid(document.getElementById('form'))" name="submit" value="Готово"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    function valid(form){
            var fail = false;
            var name = form.name.value;
            var password = form.password.value;
            var Repassword = form.Repassword.value;
            var state = form.state.value;
            if( name == "" || name==" "){
                fail = "Вы не ввели свое имя!";
            }
            else if(password == ""){
                fail = "Вы не ввели пароль";
            }
            else if(password != Repassword){
                fail = "пароли не совпадают";
            }
            else if(state == ""){
                fail = "Укажите пол";

            }


            if(fail){
                alert(fail)

            } else{
        }
```

Почему когда я заполняю форму (просто ввожу символы чтобы проверить) и после нажимаю готово. У меня не не вылезает окошка если я например не заполню какою нибудь форму (я всё подключил в хроме) 
вот типа такого окошка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните как вы подключаете js к сайту. Напрямую или с помощью расширения? Если расширением то могут быть дополнительные проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript.js"></script>
> ```

1. А путь к файлу (в атрибуте `src`) кто указывать будет?
2. Атрибут `type` неверный - лучше его вообще удалить.

> ```
> <input type = "submit" onclick="valid(document.getElementById('form'))" name="submit" value="Готово"/>
> ```

Надо не на `click` подписываться, а на отправку формы.

> ```
>     function valid(form){
> ```

Что-то подозрительный отступ. Это точно глобальная функция, а не локальная внутри самовызывающейся?

Comment: а `text/javascript.js` чем Вам не путь )?

Comment: @Igor, путь вообще-то пишется в атрибуте `src`, а не `type`. Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Тогда он у вас не подключен
 ???

Вот рабочий код:

```
function valid(form){
            var fail = false;
            var name = form.name.value;
            var password = form.password.value;
            var RePassword = form.RePassword.value;
            var state = form.state.value;
            if( name == "" || name==" "){
                fail = "Вы не ввели свое имя!";
            }
            else if(password == ""){
                fail = "Вы не ввели пароль";
            }
            else if(password != RePassword){
                fail = "пароли не совпадают";
            }
            else if(state == ""){
                fail = "Укажите пол";

            }


            if(fail){
                alert(fail);} 
        }
```

Comment: js это другой файл

Comment: Я понял. Я не вижу в коде пути до скрипта

Comment: <script type="text/javascript.js"></script> ЭТО?

Comment: Должно быть <scrtpt src="путь до скрипта.js"></script> А У ТЕБЯ

Comment: я написал как вы сказали и всё равно нету чего я хотел. Чтобы когда не заполненное поле у тебя открывалось окошко что укажите пол если его не указали

Comment: Может после alert(fail) точку с запятой прописать

Comment: не помогло. Может это проблема в хроме? Может вы знаете как там в настройках поставить чтобы такие окошки высвечивались или это не в настройках?

Comment: Это как раз легко проверить. Напишите сразу за <body> вызов алерта: <script> alert('test alert'); <\script>  Это весь код функции? У вас там скобки после нижнего else не хватает.

Comment: Косяк с Repassword и RePassword замените везде